Quirks in Stack Overflow "how do you feel about online communities" survey
I have just completed the anonymous survey titled "stack overflow: how do you feel about online communities", following an advert presently on unix.SE:

One of the questions is:


Finding solutions to complex problems is hard. Sometimes even a quick survey can be hard, too. Make sure to answer with four here. Whether paid or free, company-sanctioned or personal preference, what is the optimal number of tools you would like to use in a typical day?

When the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail;
the optimal number of tools I would like to use in a day is certainly 5+.
Why then am I asked to Make sure to answer with four here?
Also, the last six questions in the survey are repeated from the first six; is that a bug? The boxes were all checked and answers filled in just as I had left them.

While I can't answer on why the last six questions are duplicates, I can answer about the "Make sure to answer with four here" question: It's just a way to just make sure that the person who's taking the survey is actually paying attention; similar to audits in the review queues.
This isn't something exclusive to Stack Overflow surveys, it's something that's pretty common among survey sites. Especially the ones that pay people for their responses.
The people who run the surveys don't want nonsense answers from people that don't read the questions or just blaze through as fast as possible. If someone answers incorrectly here, most likely their responses just won't be considered.

While attention check questions are common in surveys, this one is phrased in a rather confusing way. Of course it should not be too obvious that a question is an attention check, but in this case I can imagine that honest survey-takers misunderstand and answer incorrectly (like OP) while dishonest survey-takers that are aware that check questions exist and know what to look for will probably still spot it.

@Marijn Actually, I did answer "four", because that's what the instructions said, but I hoped for a little flag to pop up and say, "Ah, we see you are paying attention", or something like that. Maybe the asterisk means something related to that?

@Conrado yes the flavour text is trying to tell you that it is a test, but as per usual it's as ambiguous as it could be possibly made. Perhaps on purpose to throw off LLM-driven software algorithms, but golly I do not hope that poor UX is going to be the standard to ward off the machines.

The normal way would be to ask some question with a fairly obvious answer and then ask it a second time later.
